# Converting Boolean bean creation to boolean using Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, boolean

So, I have something like this in one of my java files:

```java
@Resource(name = "initializationCache")
Boolean initializationCache;
```

In a config file, I have this:

```xml
<bean id="initializationCache" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="${initialization.cache}" />
</bean>
```

How would I go about making this work using a primitive boolean?

Comment: That's basically it, autoboxing will unbox `Boolean` to `boolean`.

Comment: But I would prefer to have the initializationCache to default to false if for some reason the config isn't pulled in right. As it is now, it will be null, I believe.

Comment: What happens if you just change `Boolean` to `boolean` in your Java code?

Comment: @Grzegorz I get this: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'initializationCache' must be of type [boolean], but was actually of type [java.lang.Boolean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one way to go would be to declare a setter of `Boolean` type and let it assign the value to a field of `boolean` type, i.e.

```
boolean initializationCache;

@Resource(name = "initializationCache")
public void setInitializationCache(Boolean b) {
  this.initializationCache = b;
}
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Yes, that could work, though I'd want to do a null check, I think. I actually found a different solution that was more specific to my particular application but this answer seems like probably the best way for pre 3.0 Spring.

Answer (score 9):

In Spring 3 you can do it without intermediate bean using `@Value`:

```
@Value("${initialization.cache}")
boolean initializationCache;
```

Comment: Is there a way without going to Spring 3?

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted since this would have been a good answer if I was on 3.0+.